# Filter item from a dict and process a subset

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

I have a list of dictionaries and I want to select the items corresponding to the keys that are in a a separate list (note: we can assume that each `dict` contains the keys). Furthermore I want to process a *subset* of the selected items.

As an example, given:

```
keys_of_interest = ['a', 'b']
all_items =[ 
    {'a' : value_a1, 'b' : value_b1, 'c' : ...},
    {'a' : value_a2, 'b' : value_b2, 'c' : ...},
    ...
]
```

The result I want is obtained by extracting the values corresponding to `a` and `b` and apply `fun` only to `a`, i.e.:

```
[
    [fun(value_a1), value_b1],
    [fun(value_a2), value_b2],
    ...
]
```

The key-extraction part can be accomplished via:

```
from operator import itemgetter
[itemgetter(*keys_of_interest)(el) for el in all_items]
```

Is there any (elegant) way to combine itemgetter with a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If elegance is the priority, you can transform the dicts first, and then use `itemgetter` without further tweaking. To do this you need to separate the keys for which you want to apply a function from those for which you just want the original values -- which I think is a good thing to do in any case.

First, set up

```
keys_of_interest = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
keys_for_func = ['a', 'b']  # with this approach you can apply a func to multiple keys

func = lambda x: x ** 2  # for demo
all_dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5},
             {'a': 6, 'b': 7, 'c': 8, 'd': 9, 'e': 10}]
```

Then this is what I'd do:

```
transformed = ({k: func(v) if k in keys_for_func else v for k, v in d.items()}
               for d in all_dicts)
result = list(map(itemgetter(*keys_of_interest), transformed))
```

Result:

```
[(1, 4, 3, 4), (36, 49, 8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't a super tidy way to do this.  One way might be:

```
getter = itemgetter(*keys_of_interest[1:])
def process_dict(d):
    return_value = [fun(d[keys_of_interest[0]])]
    return_value.extend(getter(d))
    return return_value

result = [process_dict(d) for d in all_items]
```

If you're targeting a recent-enough version of python, this can be done similarly with a bit less subscripting...

```
first_key, *other_keys = keys_of_interest
getter = itemgetter(*other_keys)
def process_dict(d):
    return_value = [fun(d[first_key])]
    return_value.extend(getter(d))
    return return_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this too inelegant?

```
from operator import itemgetter
result = [(f(x), *others) for x, *others in [
    itemgetter(*keys_of_interest)(el) for el in all_items]
    ]
```

Or in older versions:

```
from operator import itemgetter
result = [(f(x[0]), x[1:]) for x in [
    itemgetter(*keys_of_interest)(el) for el in all_items]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.5+ solution:

setup:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> keys_of_interest = ['a', 'b', 'c'] # 3 keys to show unpacking at work
>>> all_items = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7, 'd': 8}]
>>> fun = str # some silly demo function
```

Apply `map` and the Python 3.5 unpacking:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: (fun(x[0]), *x[1:]),
...     (itemgetter(*keys_of_interest)(el) for el in all_items)))
[('1', 2, 3), ('5', 6, 7)]
```